# SQL query multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am attempting to combine the following queries. I have **three tables**.

- 1 is a table containing login info.
- 2 is a table containing variables.
- 3 is a table containing the variables data.

For each record in `table 1 (login)`, there are corresponding records in `tables 2 & 3`. There is a **key** that is **unique** across all **three** tables, as well as a **key** in the variables that corresponds to the variable data.

I would like to pull out **unique records** in `table 1` (login) based on a value, that also has records in `tables 2 & 3` based on specific values.

Currently I am getting way too many records. I have been able to put the various result sets into Excel, `sort by key and remove duplicates`. Since `table 2` contains two different variables that I need, I still have two records displayed for each since the data is unique. Make sense?

**Table 1**:

```
WebSecurityLoginID PK
ProgramID FK
```

**Table 2**:

```
ProgramID PK FK
VariableNo PK
```

**Table 3**:

```
WebSecurityLoginID PK FK
ProgramID PK FK
VaraibleNo PK FK
```

So for tables 2 & 3 I have the following:

```
SELECT 
    d.WebSecurityLoginID, d.LoginVariableData
FROM 
    dbo.WebLoginVariableData d
WHERE 
    d.ProgramID = 101809 
    AND d.VariableNo = 1 
    AND d.LoginVariableData = 'not yet responded' 

UNION 

SELECT 
    d.WebSecurityLoginID, d.LoginVariableData
FROM 
    dbo.WebLoginVariableData d
WHERE 
    d.ProgramID = 101809 
    AND d.VariableNo = 2 
    AND d.LoginVariableData = 'EAST'
ORDER BY 
    d.WebSecurityLoginID
```

This gives me more records than needed. I need the `intersection`.

I also want to extract the following information from table 1 that is related to tables 2 & 3:

```
SELECT 
    w.WebSecurityLoginID, w.LoginID, w.LastName, w.FirstName, w.EmailAddress
FROM 
    dbo.WebSecurityLogin w 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.WebLoginVariables v ON w.ProgramID = v.ProgramID 
WHERE 
    w.ProgramID = 101809
```

I'm not sure how to put it all together. I think I need an `INNER JOIN`, but when I attempt, I get unexpected results.

Help please. I've tried following several examples, but I'm still not getting the anticipated results.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please add the structure of all 3 tables in your question?

Comment: Yes, I realized that after posting and updated with primary keys and foreign keys. Hope that helps.

Comment: One more thing - which DBMS?

Comment: MS SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: please show your table schema!!

Comment: Can you post some dummy data and expected results? It doesn't seem very clear like this

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the queries, because on yours for table 2 & 3 there is only a table.
I assume that WebLoginVariableData is table 3 and WebSecurityLogin is table 1.

For the intersection you can check for the values that appear twice in your query, but it's possible to rewrite the query without the `UNION`

```
SELECT WebSecurityLoginID
     , LoginVariableData
FROM   dbo.WebLoginVariableData
WHERE  ProgramID = 101809 
 AND   ((VariableNo = 1 AND LoginVariableData = 'not yet responded')
     OR (VariableNo = 2 AND LoginVariableData = 'EAST'))
GROUP BY WebSecurityLoginID, LoginVariableData
HAVING COUNT(WebSecurityLoginID) = 2
   AND COUNT(LoginVariableData) = 2
ORDER BY WebSecurityLoginID
```

In SQLServer 2012 the `INTERSECT` operator has been added to get something like

```
SELECT d.WebSecurityLoginID, d.LoginVariableData
FROM   dbo.WebLoginVariableData d
WHERE  d.ProgramID = 101809 
  AND  d.VariableNo = 1 
  AND  d.LoginVariableData = 'not yet responded' 
INTERSECT
SELECT d.WebSecurityLoginID, d.LoginVariableData
FROM   dbo.WebLoginVariableData d
WHERE  d.ProgramID = 101809 
  AND  d.VariableNo = 2 
  AND  d.LoginVariableData = 'EAST'
ORDER BY d.WebSecurityLoginID
```

I'm not sure to understand the second request, if you need to get the data from table 1 that relates to the result of the previous query it's possible to use it as a `CTE` and join it to table 1

```
WITH Security AS (
  SELECT WebSecurityLoginID
       , LoginVariableData
       , ProgramID
  FROM   dbo.WebLoginVariableData
  WHERE  ProgramID = 101809 
   AND   ((VariableNo = 1 AND LoginVariableData = 'not yet responded')
       OR (VariableNo = 2 AND LoginVariableData = 'EAST'))
  GROUP BY WebSecurityLoginID, LoginVariableData
  HAVING COUNT(WebSecurityLoginID) = 2
     AND COUNT(LoginVariableData) = 2
)
SELECT w.WebSecurityLoginID, w.LoginID, w.LastName, w.FirstName, w.EmailAddress
FROM   dbo.WebSecurityLogin w 
       INNER JOIN Security s ON w.ProgramID = s.ProgramID 
                            AND w.WebSecurityLoginID = s.WebSecurityLoginID
```

the ProgramID column has been added to the `CTE` to `JOIN` it in the main query.